# Android Studio Gradle без подключения к интернет

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

Я установил Android Studio 2.2 на машину, на которой отсутствует подключение к интернет. Когда создаётся новый проект, получаю ошибку синхронизации Gradle. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идем в:

> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle

и помечаем флажок *offline*

правда, все равно, для того чтобы оффлайновая мода работала, нужно чтобы кэш gradle был уже заполнен. А для этого надо чтобы он хотя бы раз в онлайне запустился.

Можно попробовать взять кэш из другой машины скопировав каталог `~/.gradle/caches` - но не уверен что это сработает.