# Как собрать произвольное приложение под Android без использовани gradle/ant/Android Studio

Tags: java, gradle, javac, android

Я хочу собрать какое-то произвольное приложение, к примеру, найденное на Гитхабе: https://github.com/heruoxin/Clip-Stack (само приложение у меня уже есть, потому не надо мне слать ссылки на бинарные сборки)

Зачастую, в комплекте с приложением есть обертка для Gradle, иногда свойства проекта от Eclipse, иногда ничего нет. Сам процесс, не смотря на кажущуюся простоту, достаточно сложен: надо выкачать SDK/NDK (теперь прямых ссылок на них не дают, но об этом позже), настроить переменные окружения и запустить `./gradlew`, а после выкачивания 200-300 мегабайт зависимостей, очень часто вылезает какая-то ошибка (к примеру о том, что нужна проприетарная Java 8). И даже если ошибки нет, сборка может сожрать 2-3 гигабайта памяти, весь своп и затем упасть, ссылаясь на недостаток памяти (ведь нынче все богатые и девелопят исключительно на макбуках последнего поколения, причем все торопятся - потому все это собирается в 10 потоков, отжирая в 10 раз больше памяти). Кроме того, такой подход не дает возможности скомпилировать приложение на изолированной от сети машине: [Android Studio Gradle без подключения к интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597287/)

**Вопрос: как собрать приложение без использования толстых сборщиков?**

Пожалуй основная проблема происходит из-за сложности разруливания зависимостей. Например, для сборки приложения выше, мне понадобились:

```
support-fragment-25.2.0.aar
support-compat-25.2.0.aar
support-annotations-25.2.0.jar
support-core-utils-25.2.0.aar
support-core-ui-25.2.0.aar
appcompat-v7-22.2.1.aar
recyclerview-v7-25.2.0.aar
cardview-v7-25.2.0.aar
```

Но быстро выяснилось, что в 25-й версии что-то было изменено и она не подходит, скомпилированное приложение просто падает. Я выкачал множество версий aar-пакетов и самодельными скриптами проиндексировал их, создавая самодельную базу символов, но столкнулся с проблемой, что в какой-то версии нет нужной фичи, а через пару версий этой фичи (или другой) уже нет. Кроме того, не очень понятно, где и как брать официальные бинарники, без проприетарного SDK Manager. В общем, я сдался.

Анализ поведения Gradle показал, что javac+dx не используются вообще, а aapt используется только для обработки картинок.

Если кто-то имеет возможность/хочет написать легковестную IDE или хотя бы скрипт для сборки приложений, то с радостью присоединюсь к проекту.

Ссылки:

1. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html - официальная инструкция ведет меня к ненавистному мной Gradle
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132753/ - здесь кратко описывается процесс сборки через javac+dx+aapt, дополнительный блеск  от jarsigner+zipalign. Это работает (проверял лично), однако, тут не описано как именно это сделать (впрочем, если почитать мануалы, то становится понятно), равно как не описано, как разруливать зависимости, что делать с ресурсами и т.д., а кроме того, как установить пакеты из SDK.
3. https://metacpan.org/pod/Android::Build - ссылка уже не рабочая, но в архивах можно найти замечательный скрипт, который мог собрать простенькие приложения под Android

В вопрос призывается **Lex Hobbit** из [Как создать модульное android приложение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686266/)

Comment: Самым разумным для вас будет подавить чувство собственной исключительности, особое мнение и установить [стандартный пакет разработчика Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)(1.9 Гб), который включает ВСЕ необходимое и даже нужную версию JDK, при этом полностью настроен на работу, а также всем сердцем полюбить Gradle в кратчайшие сроки, либо купить много валерьянки с глицином, потому что современная сборка APK без помощи Android Studio способна "добить" любого.

Comment: Моя исключительность происходит от того, что я наверное единственный, кто не может понять: зачем для сборки пустяшного приложения чуть сложнее хелловорлда, нужно выкачивать гигабайты файлов и занимать гигабайты оперативки. Моя исключительность в том, что в свое время для сборки программ хватало нескольких мегабайт оперативки, а делали эти программы намного больше среднестатистического Андроид-приложения, разрабатываемых в наше время. И я исключительно не могу понять и принять сложившуюся ситуацию вокруг разработки, мне просто это противно.

Comment: Если вас неудержимо тянет в олдскул и прямо все так противно, что оно такое функциональное, то касательно android-разработки можете попробовать Eclipse с ADT ранних версий (времен 2-го андроида), это то еще дно, конечно, по современным представлениям, но как раз все будет мило вашему сердцу: объемы в мегабайтах, сборка через Ant, все ручками .. Правда не знаю, как оно там будет с современными Android API взаимодействовать, но теоретически приложение под API9 будет работать и на API26, естественно с всякими Material Design и прочим мейнстримом придется,  видимо, попрощаться.

Comment: ".. зачем для сборки пустяшного приложения чуть сложнее хелловорлда .." - потому что могут. А вообще "в ваше время" (оно же и мое, ибо начинал я в далекие 80-ые) средства разработки были несколько проще в плане функциональности, а так же решаемых задач и мне бы, например, не хотелось вернуться к инструментам разработки того времени, мне уже просто лень проделывать огромные объемы бестолковой работы - за меня ее сделает IDE и мне не жалко ни гигабайтов ни гигагерцев, стоят они сравнительно не дорого в наше время.

Comment: Кроме того, IDE неизвестно, сложнее хеловорда будет ваше приложение или проще, а возможности оно предоставляет для максимально сложного проекта, чтобы его разработка была комфортной и с наименьшим количеством рутины.  Лайт-версий для любителей хеловордов как то не предусмотрено, к вашему сожалению.

Comment: Ну, свои собственные проекты я и разрабатываю в Эклипсе. Правда, из-за последнего апдейта все сломалось и я почему-то могу делать приложения только под 19-е АПИ, все остальное порождает миллионы ошибок. Но надо собирать каким-то образом чужие приложения. Импортировать в эклипс - не получается, я даже пытался написать систему для "конвертирования" структуры приложений в тот формат, что понимает эклипс - не получилось. Не патчить же приложения бинарно, если есть исходники?

Comment: А лайт-версии IDE для любителей хелловорлдов были: это и Android::Build (не знаю зачем автор его удалил), и старое сановское WTK, которое использовалось во времена MIDP на мобилочках. Причем мидлеты компилировались за секунды на очень древнем железе. Конечно, это очень хорошо, что не надо таскать за собой таблицы клавиатур от каждой модели телефона, можно выделять память мегабайтами в рантайме и не бояться вылета приложения или перезагрузки телефона, но вот я почему-то не готов только для системы сборки выделить сотню мегабайт зависимостей, которые gradlе ест только для себя (даже не SDK!!!).

Comment: Он далеко не исключителен в нелюбви к grandle, т. к. на это есть объективные причины и любить эту штуку, которая лишает программиста контроля над сборкой, качая сама что хочет и когда хочет, не за что.

Comment: Да, 50 секунд, когда собирается проект это не быстро. Нужны средства побыстрее. Просто когда работаешь над большим проектом, то каждый гиг на щету. Ведь студия не единая, что занимает 2-3 гига

Answer (score 5):

Как уже написали в комментарии к вопросу - сборка и "жизнь" без *Android Studio*  - очень непроста. Но раз условия диктуют необходимость жить без нее, то будем адаптироваться.

### Предварительная подготовка среды сборки

- [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) (в самом низу страницы в разделе *"Get just the command line tools"*)
- Настройка переменных среды

  - `JAVA_BIN` путь до *bin* папки *Java JDK*
  - `ANDROID_SDK` путь до папки с *Android SDK*
- Приватный ключ для подписи *APK* файла (назовем его `release_key.keystore`)

  keytool  -genkey -v -keystore  release_key.keystore -alias alias_name  -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048  -validity 10000
- Написать код приложения и проверить правильность структуры приложения

### Пошаговый алгоритм сборки

Пошаговый алгоритм сборки *Android*  приложения  без использования *gradle / ant / Android Studio* (предполагается, что весь исходный код, включая `AndroidManifest.xml`, ресурсы, необходимые библиотеки у нас уже есть):

1. Создаем `R.java`, PK файл из ассетов, ресурсов и `AndroidManifest.xml` и получаем `MyApplication.apk.unaligned` используя используя `aapt package`
2. Компилируем *java* исходники в `*.class` исполльзуя для этого `javac`
3. Создаем исполняемый файл `classes.dex` из `*.class` используя `dx`
4. Добавляем в `MyApplication.apk.unaligned` файл `classes.dex` используя `aapt add`
5. Подписываем `MyApplication.apk.unaligned` с дебажным или релизным ключем
6. Выравниваем наш APK используя `zipalign` и вуаля!

### Создание .aar библиотеки

Алгоритм создания библиотеки .aar схож с алгоритмом создания APK файла.

- в п.1 вместо `R.java` создаем `R.txt` используя `aapt` с опцией `--output-text-symbols` и название архива с расширением `*.aar`
- в п.3 вместо *classes.dex* создаем *classes.jar* используя

  jar cvf classes.jar *.class
- в п.4 добавляем *classes.jar* в  архива с расширением `*.aar` и на этом все, наша отдельная *AAR* библиотека создана

**P/S** чуть позже поправлю и можно написать скриптик для сборки.

И кажется, как бы все было проще, если бы всеже перешли к [Jack&Jill](https://source.android.com/source/jack), но как [сообщают](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) разработчики - они осознали, во что это им обойдется. Ниже приведен процесс сборки APK с использованием тулчейна Jack.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как насчет внешних библиотек, библиотек поддержки без публичных репозиториев? без них сейчас трудно представить андроид-приложение, если оно немногим сложнее "привет мир"

Comment: @pavlofff я это напишу, чуть позже... пока написал быстрый вариант сборки, вечером добавлю остальное, как только с работы вернусь =) Спасибо за коммент - учту

Comment: Собственно, ради всего этого и создан вопрос. Это главное.

Comment: Кстати, не надо копировать ответ из агнлоязычного туториала. Пункты 1 и 4 можно совместить, сделав заготовку, которую потом и патчить - будет более быстрая сборка. Можно компилять в декс только нужные файлы - тоже ускорение. aapt add не нужен, достаточно обычного зип-архиватора. Зип-алигн нужен только для маркета, для дебага не обязательно (оно нужно для ммапа ассетов).

Comment: @bukkojot по поводу zipalign - это понятно, просто я в итоге всегда собираю релизную сборку... которая потом отдается заказчику, а он уже в свою очередь решает выгружать на маркет или нет =)

Comment: @bukkojot может вам стоит глянуть в сторону https://buckbuild.com? не тестил еще по ресурсам, но по скорости сборки хороший прирост. Я в ручную билжу только тогда, когда пересобираю приложения и нет исходников ... Осталось дописать как делать aar  с apk

Comment: Выравниваете и отдаете заказчику? А он про ключи в курсе? Просто интересно. Если приложение пересобирается, то внутри уже есть все нужное, то после патчи пары байтиков нам не нужны никакие дополнительные ресурсы или библиотеки. Если же мы собираем приложение из исходников, как в примере выше - тут начинается пляска с *.aar файлами и непонятно как их подбирать и где брать (по итогам своей работы я сделал скрипт, который распаковывал ресурсы в отдельные директории и прекомпилял их все разом), хорошо бы это увидеть.

Comment: @bukkojot "..непонятно как их подбирать и где брать ..": support библиотеки google можно скачать через SDK Manager -> Extras -> Android Support repository - собранные .aar, Support Library - исходники, будет создан локальный maven-репозиторий со всеми версиями суппорт-библиотек на диске (размер в районе 400Мб). Внешние не гугл библиотеки - [jcenter](https://bintray.com/)

Comment: @pavlofff, а насколько это официальные/заслуживающие доверия места (исключая то, что качается через SDK Manager, здесь вопросов быть не может). А касаемо подбора, я видимо выразился не совсем понятно, я делал такую штуку: парсил директиву import в исходниках и смотрел какие классы импортируются, затем искал в локальной базе библиотек эти символы. Локальная база была сделана на основе парсинга AAR-архивов, банальный список файлов, чего вроде бы и достаточно, но порой нехватает каких-то методов или методы имеют разные сигнатуры, а то **внутри AAR-файла несколько jar-файлов**, что вообще загадка

Comment: jcenter - фактически официальный репозиторий android для сторонних внешних библиотек, именно он по умолчанию указан в качестве внешнего репозитория в Android Studio, так же часто используется MavenCentral. Формат AAR - это формат [Android библиотеки](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents), он гораздо "объемнее", чем JAR и может включать ресурсы, другие библиотеки и нативные модули.

Answer (score 1):

Можно собрать под Intellij IDEA без Gradle. Еще пару лет назад я практиковал такое... Врукопашную собираешь все `jar/aar` вручную прокидываешь зависимости и вперед.

Есть фанаты сборки Android под maven, ах ну да - это же толстый сборщик :)

Был опыт сборки под Ant - не знаю насколько он толст для ТС...

В любом случае, полностью присоединяюсь к @pavlofff:

> всем сердцем полюбить Gradle в кратчайшие сроки, либо купить много валерьянки с глицином, потому что современная сборка APK без помощи Android Studio способна "добить" любого

Comment: Maven быстрее Gradle

Comment: Так, первый выстрел в холиваре есть :)

Comment: Intellij IDEA - оно уже не кушает гигабайты оперативы? А что касаемо "добить" - я могу применить sed-магию и быстренько все эти новомодные СуперКрутыеАктивити быстренько деградировать до простых Активити с первой версией.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю такие аргументы. Гигабайт оперативной памяти стоит грубо говоря 1000 рупь, цена билета в кино на пару с девушкой ну или похода в кофейню. Ну млин, неужели сложно?

Comment: @Alex78191 https://buckbuild.com, быстрее всего вышеперечисленного =)

Comment: Barmaley, дело даже в том, что этот gradle не работает или тормозит и занимает много памяти. Дело в том, что он лишает программиста контроля над проектом, качая что захочет, когда захочет и ставя в полную зависимость от себя. Гугл хочет лишить программистов права выбора, обращаться с ними как с рабами. Например, отключил после обновления сдк-менеджер, заставляя ставить свою глючную студию, которой люди не хотят пользоваться. При все этом gradle еще и так глючно написан, что у меня, например, gradlew просто не может запустится и никто не может сказать почему.

Comment: @Eugene все с точностью до наоборот: Gradle освобождает прогера от лишнего знания о ходе сборке, их шагах, где брать зависимости, откуда чего качать. Сконцентрируйтесь на коде и забудьте о проблемах сборки.

Comment: Barmaley, эта глючная фигня сама что нибудь обновит и будете 3 месяца искать, почему вдруг прекрасно работавшая программа ни с того ни с сего стала глючить. Гугл плей забит подобными отзывами о всех популярных программах.

Comment: Вот тут хорошо написано про это http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/TataTutu.html . Создателем данного сервиса, между прочим. "Вот тогда я и получил один из главных уроков в области программной архитектуры: для наиболее ответственных, критических задач вы должны использовать инструмент одним уровнем абстракции ниже, чем это было бы в идеале." С gradle все еще хуже - вы даже не можете приспособится к его глюкам и глюкам библиотек, потому что он будет постоянно обновляться и приносить новые глюки.

Comment: Любой инструмент требует определенной техники безопасности, конечно если бездумно его использовать, то выстрел в ногу гарантирован