# Как установить Viber или WhatsApp на Android-2.3

Tags: android, android-sdk

Всем привет. 
**Знатоки - ВНИМАНИЕ ВОПРОС!**

1. Как уставить Viber or WhatsApp на андроид 2.3.4. Viber - официально,
   уже отказался от поддержки старого (мин. OS-4.0), а у  WhatsApp-2.16
   (OS 2.3-4.0) тоже какая то непонятная проблема, не не видит сеть
   после установки и проблемы с настройками даты (менять дату
   пробовал), а WhatsApp-2.17 не ставится тк. поддерживает только с
   Андроид-4.0.
2. Прошить на телефон Андроид-4.0 не могу, т.к. места (ROM) не хватает
   на    телефоне.

В наличии, старый: 
*Fly IQ270 
CPU: MTK-6573
RAM: 256
ROM: 512 + microCD
Экран: 3.75", сенсор, 480x320*

PS/ пробовал обмануть. Прописал версию 4.4.2 и АПИ 19 - все установилось но блин не работает. хотя после того как я подменил АПИ еще и другой софт перестал работать, в общем нужно перепрошивать полностью, хотя телефон вроди как - работает нормально.

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос - в самом вопросе. Если производитель ПО официально не поддерживает Вашу ОС, то ответ - поставить так, чтобы нормально работало нет возможности.

Comment: Спасибо. Да Вы несомненно - правы. Просто я кое что опустил, фишка в том что, до обнуления телефона - стоял Viber 5 или 4-й, к сожалению не помню ...

Comment: Это ничего не меняет. Скорее всего стояла старая версия с отключением обновлений и, возможно, даже все это работало. Но новую версию с маркета вы не сможете нормально заставить работать. Как вариант, найти где-то старую версию в виде apk файла и попробовать поставить вручную - но не факт, что будет рабоать нормально. Посмотрите [здесь](https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=236581&st=120), может что- то найдете.

Comment: нашел. VIber v.2.0 ставится, заводится, а вот регистрация у нее по 4 знакам, а код приходит 6 знаков. Телефонный звонок обрывается ... и тд.
v.2.3-4.3 сразуже требуют обновления, даже до регистрации дело не доходит. кстати как говорят люди, кто ставил v.5-6 им приходит код из 4-х цифр, ну а звонок тоже обрывается.
PS/ я его пилю уже 3-е суток, многое перепробовал и решил написать сюда ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Как уже сказали ранее - никак.

Но в пост-советских странах нету такого определения (меня с детства учили фразой "нет слова "не могу", есть слово "не хочу", которым просто задолбали). И более того, люди готовы тратить тысячи часов своего времени для реализации мечты, чтобы при этом не тратить лишнюю копейку, которой просто нет. Я тоже хочу поправить драйвер планшета, чтобы можно было работать с разбитым тачскрином, ведь купить новый планшет - это около 100 баксов, а я безработный, найти работу не могу и эта сотня баксов для меня - это гигантские деньги.

Поискать старый дистр конечно можно (именно поэтому я храню пакеты с того года, когда купил планшет и научился их добывать через адб). Но тут ресурс по программированию, а не по пуско-наладочным работам.

Для начала подумаем, а что собственно может не работать и почему:

1. Поменяли API. Вариантов много, от банального долбления apiv1.example.com в старых версиях, замененного на apiv2.example.com в новых версиях, заканчивая тем, что все переписали 20 раз и старые серваки выключили.
2. Используют новое модное API для отрисовки гламурных кнопочек, которые требуют свежую систему.
3. Используют какое-то системное API, не видимое пользователю, а в случае использования бинарников, собранных с NDK, мы получаем бинарную привязку. Это хуже всего (ну, по крайней мере для меня, в пределах моей компетенции).

Если я что-то упустил, то надеюсь, что достопочтенное сообщество дополнит. А узнать, где именно оно падает, можно при помощи `adb logcat` или самого `logcat`, запущенного прямо на девайсе. Как правило, в консольку валятся миллионы сообщений о том, что прямо сейчас делает приложение, а то и целые трейсы, с указанием классов, где произошло падение. Приложение надо сначала установить, а оно не хочет? Думаю, про распаковку через `apktool` говорить не стоит.

Зная, где происходит падение, пытаемся изолировать этот участок. Для этого лучше попробовать провести деобфускацию того выхлопа, что дает нам `apktool`, или по крайней мере идентифицировать библиотеки. К примеру, если по какому-то событию мы пытаемся обратиться к саппорт-либе, то смело можем заменять его на вызов попроще, а то и вообще выкинуть. Аналогично можно попробовать сделать с бинарником. Правда библиотеки придется бинарно патчить, по крайней мере мне неизвестны инструменты уровня `apktool` для простой пересборки.

Лично я бы посоветовал как-то распарсить документацию и получить список классов.методов() и их версии, чтобы знать, что именно дергать нельзя. Наверняка такой список где-то в сети существует, я не сильно искал, если кто знает - пусть поможет. Потом можно попробовать как-то полуавтоматическим образом, скажем через регулярочки, порезать/заменить вызовы к старому апи.

Лично я сам такое хочу сделать для убирания АппКомпатов и прочего говна, которое у меня не собирается. Я даже спрашивал как правильно собирать приложения [Как собрать произвольное приложение под Android без использовани gradle/ant/Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687556/), но ответа пока еще не поступило. Если будет нужно и дальше, я наверное напишу даунгрейдилку Апи, но пока это для меня не приоритетная задача.

Comment: Да зачем же столько трындеть :)

Answer (score 0):

**Решение: обновление OS до актуальной версии.**

1. При попытке скачать и установить, с GooglePlay, на Android-5.1 -
   качается и устанавливается. При попытке активировать просит -
   обновить Viber.

   2. При попытке скачать и установить, с GooglePlay, на Android-5.1 -
      качается и устанавливается. При попытке активировать - активируется,
      потом вырубается и при повторном запуске - просит обновить Viber.
   3. Нашел Viber-6.9.5.apk. При попытке установить, на Android-5.1, -
      устанавливается. При попытке активировать просит - обновить Viber.
   4. При попытке скачать и установить, с GooglePlay, на Android-6.0 -
      качается и устанавливается. При попытке активировать - активируется.
   5. Viber-6.9.5.apk. При попытке установить, на Android-6.0, -
      устанавливается. При попытке активировать - активируется Viber.

**ИТОГО:** **Viber - галимая прога.**

Т.к. получается, что, по задумке авторов Viber для каждой версии Viber нужна актуальная версия OS Android. И если Вы вдруг удалили свою версию из устройсва или пытаетесь сменить номер (аккаунт) и у Вас не актуальная OS - ***вешайтесь***.

> ***PS.*** Возможно у кого то есть другие решения - просьба поделиться!

Comment: Ищите ломанную старую версию, не проверяющую обновления.